# cmake and /opt/cmake/bin/cmake showing different version

Tags: c++, cmake

I am quite new to C++ programming and cmake. Kindly bear with me if the question seems simple.

I am building an application for which cmake 3.9.0 is the minimum version required.

```
Setup.sh: Building rpclib with libc++.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.9.0 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.5.1
```

So I planned to upgrade the cmake version and followed the below link.

[cmake_installation](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/operating_systems/linux/installation/downloading_compiling_and_installing_cmake_on_linux.php)

Note : Just to be clear, I don't want to purge the existing version as it might affect the **ROS** environment in my system.

I have completed the installation and results given below.

When I run `cmake -version`:

```
kk@kk-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15ISK:~/cmake-3.9.0$ cmake -version 
cmake version 3.5.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
kk@kk-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15ISK:~/cmake-3.9.0$
```

And when I run `/opt/cmake/bin/cmake -version`

```
kk@kk-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15ISK:~/cmake-3.9.0$ /opt/cmake/bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.9.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
kk@kk-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15ISK:~/cmake-3.9.0$
```

And issue/error with the application build remains the same as before.

Could you please help me to update cmake or fix this existing version issue.

Thank you

KK

Comment: This just sounds like a PATH issue. You've got to change the PATH variable so that Setup.sh finds your cmake before the earlier version. Try this before you run Setup.sh `export PATH=/opt/cmake/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: @john Thank you so much mate. The error is fixed now after setting the path variable before running setup.sh. If you could write this as answer I would accept and close it.

Comment: OK, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just sounds like a PATH issue. You've got to change the PATH variable so that Setup.sh finds your cmake before the earlier version. Try this before you run Setup.sh

```
export PATH=/opt/cmake/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

@john answer is correct, but it could affect the existing ROS system, as the first entry of the `PATH`-variable would be used. So you would need to "unexport" the `PATH` again to the old settings to be save with the ROS system.

Assuming your script "setup.sh" is some kind of build-script, which does build your software with cmake.

You should save the current `PATH` variable in your script first, like

```
ORIGINAL_PATH=${PATH}
```

Now export the new `PATH` variable as @john already mentioned, like

```
export PATH=/opt/cmake/bin:${PATH}
```

After the run of setup.sh (again build-script assumed) you should restore the old `PATH`-variable, so your build-script does not change the user-global settings.

```
export PATH=${ORIGINAL_PATH}
```